vue-advanced-cropper not working properly in vuejs3
i am using vue-advanced-cropper in vuejs3. The problem is when i open the page for first time, the cropper works, then i go to some other page, and when i again come to same page, then only the dots for cropper comes, but i am unable to drag, resize and crop the image.
below is some part of the code:
    <b-modal
    id="images-popup"
    v-model="imgCropModal"
    body-class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-6"
    content-class=""
    centered
    hide-header
    hide-footer
    no-close-on-backdrop
>
    <div
        class="cropper-container"
        :style="{width: '400px', height: '400px'}"
    >
        <cropper
            class="cropper"
            :src="tobeCropedImg"
            ref="cropper"
            :stencil-size="{
                width: 220,
                height: 220
            }"
            :canvas="{
                height: 220,
                width: 220
            }"
            :stencil-component="$options.components.CircleStencil"
        ></cropper>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <button @click="crop" class="btn btn-success">
            Crop
        </button>
    </div>
</b-modal>

<script>
import { Cropper, CircleStencil } from 'vue-advanced-cropper'
import 'vue-advanced-cropper/dist/style.css';
export default {
components: {
    CameraIcon,
    Cropper,
    CircleStencil
},
data:{
    imgCropModal: false,
    tobeCropedImg: null,
    croppedImageType: null,
},
methods:{
            uploadLogoFile(e) {
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
            this.formData.logo = e.target.files[0];
            this.uploadedLogoPath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
            this.isdelete = false;
            
            const blob = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (event) => {
                const arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
                const mimeType = this.getMimeType(arrayBuffer, e.target.files[0]?.type);
                
                this.tobeCropedImg = blob;
                this.croppedImageType = mimeType;
            };

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
            this.imgCropModal = true;
        }
    },
    crop(){
        const { canvas } = this.$refs.cropper.getResult({
            width: 220,   // Set your desired width
            height: 220,
        });
        this.uploadedLogoPath = canvas.toDataURL(this.croppedImageType || 'image/png');
        this.formData.logo = canvas.toDataURL(this.croppedImageType || 'image/png');
        this.imgCropModal = false;
    },
    getMimeType(file, fallback = null) {
        const byteArray = (new Uint8Array(file)).subarray(0, 4);
        let header = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        header += byteArray[i].toString(16);
        }
        switch (header) {
            case "89504e47":
                return "image/png";
            case "47494638":
                return "image/gif";
            case "ffd8ffe0":
            case "ffd8ffe1":
            case "ffd8ffe2":
            case "ffd8ffe3":
            case "ffd8ffe8":
                return "image/jpeg";
            default:
                return fallback;
        }
    },
}

i have tried several things, like refreshing the cropper etc, but nothing worked.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . A way to reproduce will help. This is specific to your case, it's unknown what "go to some other page, and when i again come to same page" means, whether "page" is vue router view, which routes they are, whether keep-alive is used
